# Issue with HTML email in all versions of Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have an email for a client I'm working on. It tests fine in every program except Microsoft Outlook. Right now, the blue table at the top is extending beyond the container. The only other solution I have is to make that text an image but I'd rather not if possible. Does anyone know a fix for this?

[Screenshot of Email Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBsmN.jpg)

Here is part of the code the email I'm using. It's responsive but I've only included the desktop only code:

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
       <tr>
        <td class="no-mobile" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:black; line-height:15px; padding: 4px;font-size: 11px;text-align:center;">
         
         <p style="margin:5px 0px 20px 10px;">
          Having trouble reading this? View on the web at:<br> <a href="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/ubr-exc-M200319-searching.html " style="color:#0020ff;">https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/ubr-exc-M200319-searching.html </a><br> The following is a sponsored message. Health Union LLC does not endorse any specific product, service or treatment.
         </p>
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
       <tr>
        <td class="no-mobile" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#427bba; line-height:120%; padding: 4px;font-size: 12px;">
         <p style="margin:5px 0px 10px 10px;">
          <a href="https://media.allergan.com/products/Ubrelvy_pi.pdf?aimlink=6d15a2d396d36679ff9e8c4355c27da4&aimtoken=NTk4ODU0NS0zYTc3YmI1ZQ#page=14" style="color:#427bba;text-decoration:none;">Patient Information</a>
         </p>
        </td>
        <td class="no-mobile" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:black; line-height:120%; padding: 4px;font-size: 12px;color:#427bba;">
         <p style="margin:5px 200px 10px 0px;">
          <a href="https://www.ubrelvy.com/important-safety-information?cid=EM-Ubr_Excedrin_OTC_HU-Header_ISI" style="color:#427bba;text-decoration:none;">Important Safety Information</a>
         </p>
        </td>
        <td class="no-mobile" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:black; line-height:120%; padding: 4px;font-size: 12px;text-align:left;color:#427bba;">
         <p style="margin:5px 10px 10px 0px;">
          <a href="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/ubr-exc-M200319-searching.html" style="color:#427bba;text-decoration:none;">View in browser</a>
         </p>
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="`0" bgcolor="#38bdd1"  >
       <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style="line-height:12px; font-size:10px;color:black;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <p style="margin: 20px 0px 20px 30px;">
         UBRELVY™ is a prescription medicine used for the acute treatment of migraine attacks with or without aura in adults.<br> UBRELVY is not used to prevent migraine headaches. 
         </p>
        </td> 
       </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
       <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style="font-size:0px; line-height:27px; vertical-align: top;font-size:22px;color:#676767;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
         <p style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
           <a href="https://www.ubrelvy.com/home?cid=EM-Ubr_Excedrin_OTC_HU-Ubr_Logo">
          <img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/d-hero-1.png" width="100%" alt="UBRELVY™ is a prescription medicine used for the acute treatment of migraine attacks with or without aura in adults. UBRELVY is not used to prevent migraine headaches. Searching For Relief When A Migraine Strikes"/>
          </a>
         </p>
        </td> 
       </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style=" line-height:35px; vertical-align: top;font-family:arial;">
           <p style="text-align:left;margin:10px 0px 10px 30px;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;line-height:29px;color:#00a174">
         INTRODUCING UBRELVY
          </p> 
           <p style="text-align:left;margin:10px 0px 10px 30px;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;color:black;">
            While over-the-counter Excedrin<sup style="line-height:0px;font-size:10px;">&reg;</sup> Migraine is temporarily unavailable, talk to your healthcare provider to see if prescription UBRELVY is right for you. It’s a new medicine that treats migraine pain and symptoms once they start and has a safety profile that allows you to take it whenever, wherever you need it. 
          </p> 
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:20px 0px 20px 30px;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;color:black;">
           <a href="https://www.ubrelvy.com/home?cid=EM-Ubr_Excedrin_OTC_HU-Visit_Ubr_Button">
            <img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/visit-cta.png" width="227px" alt="Visit Ubrelvy.com"/>
           </a>
          </p> 
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:30px 0px 20px 30px;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;color:black;">
         <img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/d-on-the-go-treatment.png" width="100%" alt="A New On-The-Go-Treatment"/>
          </p> 
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:30px 0px 5px 30px;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;line-height:29px;color:#00a174">
         YOU MAY PAY AS LITTLE AS $1 PER PILL*
          </p> 
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 10px 30px;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;color:black;">
         See if you’re eligible for exclusive savings and learn more about UBRELVY now!
          </p>
           <p style="text-align:left;margin:20px 0px 20px 30px;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;color:black;">
         <a href="https://www.ubrelvy.com/savings?cid=EM-Ubr_Excedrin_OTC_HU-Discover_Savings_Button">  
           <img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/discover-cta.png" width="227px" alt="Discover Savings"/>
          </a>
          </p> 
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:10px 0px 10px 30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;line-height:15px;color:black;">
         *Terms and Conditions apply. This offer is valid only for commercially insured patients. Offer not valid for patients enrolled in Medicare, Medicaid, or other federal or state healthcare programs. <a href="https://www.ubrelvy.com/savings-terms?cid=EM-Ubr_Excedrin_OTC_HU-Savings_Program_Terms" style="text-decoration:none;color:#394fd3">Please review full Program Terms, Conditions, and Eligibility Criteria.</a> 
          </p>
           <p style="text-align:left;margin:30px 0px 5px 30px;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;line-height:29px;color:#00a174">
         DISCOVER UBRELVY
          </p>
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 0px 30px;font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;color:black;">
         The efficacy of UBRELVY was proven in 2 clinical studies with over 2,000 participants.
          </p>
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 10px 30px;font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;color:black;">
         These studies evaluated the following outcomes at 2 hours after taking 1 dose of UBRELVY:
          </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style=" line-height:35px; vertical-align: top;font-family:arial;">
          <p style="margin:10px 0px 0px 50px;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;color:black;">
         <img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/d-icon-pain-freedom.png" width="120" alt="PAIN FREEDOM(ZERO PAIN)"/>
          </p> 
         </td>
         <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style=" line-height:35px; vertical-align: top;font-family:arial;">
          <p style="margin:10px 0px 20px 20px;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;color:black;">
         <img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/d-icon-absence.png" width="220" alt="ABSENCE OF MOST BOTHERSOME MIGRAINE SYMPTOMS (LIGHT SENSITIVITY, SOUND SENSITIVITY, OR NAUSEA)"/>
          </p> 
         </td>
         <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style=" line-height:35px; vertical-align: top;font-family:arial;">
         <p style="margin:10px 0px 20px 0px;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;color:black;">
         <img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/d-icon-pain-relief.png" width="120" alt="PAIN RELIEF"/>
          </p> 
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style=" line-height:35px; vertical-align: top;font-family:arial;">
         <p style="text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 30px 30px;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;color:black;">
         The majority of patients achieved pain relief (reduction in pain) and 1 in 5 experienced total pain freedom. Many also reported absence of their most bothersome symptom.
          </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style=" line-height:35px; vertical-align: top;font-family:arial;">
         <p style="text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 20px 30px;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;color:#00a074;">
         Important Safety Information
          </p>
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 0px 30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;color:black;">
         Who should not take UBRELVY&#8482;(ubrogepant)?
          </p>
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 20px 30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;line-height:16px;color:black;">
         Do not take UBRELVY if you are taking medicines known as strong CYP3A4 inhibitors, such as ketoconazole, clarithromycin, itraconazole.
          </p>
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 0px 30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;color:black;">
         What should I tell my healthcare provider before taking UBRELVY?
          </p>
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 0px 30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;line-height:16px;color:black;">
         Tell your healthcare provider about all your medical conditions, including if you:
          </p>
           <ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 38px; line-height:20px;font-size:12px;">
           <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;color:black;"> Have liver problems</li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;color:black;">Have kidney problems</li>
                                     <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;color:black;">Are pregnant or plan to become pregnant </li>
           <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;color:black;">Are breastfeeding or plan to breastfeed </li>
                                    </ul>
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:20px 0px 20px 30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;line-height:16px;color:black;">
         <strong>Tell your healthcare provider about all the medicines you take,</strong> including prescription and over-the-counter medicines, vitamins, and herbal supplements. Your healthcare provider can tell you if it is safe to take UBRELVY with other medicines.
          </p>
           <p style="text-align:left;margin:20px 0px 0px 30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;color:black;">
         What are the most common side effects of UBRELVY?
          </p>
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 20px 30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;line-height:16px;color:black;">
         The most common side effects are nausea (4%) and sleepiness (3%). These are not all of the possible side effects of UBRELVY. 
          </p>
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:20px 0px 0px 30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;color:black;">
          What is UBRELVY&#8482; (ubrogepant)?
          </p>
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 20px 30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;line-height:16px;color:black;">
          UBRELVY is a prescription medicine used for the acute treatment of migraine attacks with or without aura in adults. UBRELVY is not used to prevent migraine headaches.
          </p>
          <p style="text-align:left;margin:20px 0px 20px 30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;line-height:16px;color:black;">
           Please see full <a href="https://media.allergan.com/products/Ubrelvy_pi.pdf?aimlink=6d15a2d396d36679ff9e8c4355c27da4&aimtoken=NTk4ODU0NS0zYTc3YmI1ZQ#page=14" style="color:#2e3192;text-decoration:none;">Patient Information</a>.
          </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style=" line-height:35px; vertical-align: top;font-family:arial;">
         <p style="text-align:center;margin:20px 0px 10px 30px;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;color:#00a074;">
          <a href="https://www.ubrelvy.com/?cid=EM-Ubr_Excedrin_OTC_HU-Footer_Ubr_Logo">
         <img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/ubrelvy-logo.png" width="200" alt="Ubrelvy Logo"/>
          </a>
          </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style=" line-height:35px; vertical-align: top;font-family:arial;">
         <p style="margin:20px 0px 20px 85px;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;color:#00a074;text-align:right;">
           <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ubrelvy">
            <img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/social-facebook.png" width="30" alt="Facebook Social Page"/>
           </a>
          </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style=" line-height:35px; vertical-align: top;font-family:arial;">
         <p style="margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;color:#00a074;text-align:center;">
           <a href="https://www.twitter.com/ubrelvy">
         <img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/social-twitter.png" width="30" alt="Twitter Social Page"/>
           </a>
          </p>
         </td>
        <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style=" line-height:35px; vertical-align: top;font-family:arial;">
         <p style="margin:20px 80px 20px 0px;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;color:#00a074;text-align:left;">
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ubrelvy">
         <img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/social-instagram.png" width="30" alt="Instagram Social Page"/>
          </a>
          </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style=" line-height:35px; vertical-align: top;font-family:arial;">
         <p style="text-align:center;margin:10px 0px 10px 30px;font-size:8px;font-weight:normal;line-height:10px;color:black;">
         PLEASE DO NOT REPLY TO THIS EMAIL. Emails sent to this account will not be read. If you would prefer not to receive further messages from<br> this sender, please <a href="#" style="color:#2e3192;text-decoration:none;">click here</a> and confirm your request. We respect your privacy.  See our <a href="https://www.allergan.com/privacy-and-terms/ccpa?cid=EM-Ubr_Excedrin_OTC_HU-Footer_California_Policy" style="text-decoration:none;color:#2e3192;">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="https://www.allergan.com/privacy-and-terms/ccpa?cid=EM-Ubr_Excedrin_OTC_HU-Footer_California_Policy" style="text-decoration:none;color:#2e3192;">California Privacy Policy statements</a>.
          </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" class="no-mobile" style=" line-height:35px; vertical-align: top;font-family:arial;">
         <p style="text-align:center;margin:20px 0px 10px 0px;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;line-height:16px;color:#00a074;">
          <a href="https://www.allergan.com?cid=EM-Ubr_Excedrin_OTC_HU-Footer_Allergan_logo">
         <img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/allergan-logo-new.png" width="150" alt="Allergan Logo"/>
             </a>
          </p>
          <p style="text-align:center;margin:10px 0px 10px 30px;font-size:8px;font-weight:normal;line-height:10px;color:black;">
         Allergan USA, Inc.<br>
         5 Giralda Farms<br>
            Madison, NJ 07940
          </p>
          <p style="text-align:center;margin:10px 0px 10px 30px;font-size:8px;font-weight:normal;line-height:10px;color:black;">
         Allergan<sup style="line-height:0px;font-size:6px;">&reg;</sup> and its design are trademarks of Allergan, Inc.<br> UBRELVY&#8482; and its design are trademarks of Allergan Pharmaceuticals International Limited.<br> All trademarks are the property of their respective owners.<br> &copy; 2020 Allergan. All rights reserved.<br> UBR133165-V1 03/20
          </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" >
       <tr>
        <td class="no-mobile" style="text-align: left; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; color: #000000">
        <p style="text-align:center;" class="footer"><a target="_blank" href="https://migraine.com/?uuid=XXXXX-XXX-XXXXXX">
           <img src="https://migraine.com/weekly/logo_masthead02_2x.png" alt="migraine.com" width="180" height="27" border="0" /></a><br />
           <a href="https://migraine.com/about-us/?uuid=XXXXX-XXX-XXXXXX" style="color:#1E7EBE;font-weight:bold;">ABOUT US</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href="https://migraine.com/contact-us/?uuid=XXXXX-XXX-XXXXXX" style="color:#1E7EBE;font-weight:bold;">CONTACT US</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href="https://migraine.com/terms-of-use/?uuid=XXXXX-XXX-XXXXXX" style="color:#1E7EBE;font-weight:bold;">TERMS OF USE</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href="https://migraine.com/privacy-policy/?uuid=XXXXX-XXX-XXXXXX" style="color:#1E7EBE;font-weight:bold;">PRIVACY POLICY</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href="https://migraine.com/about-us/community-rules/?uuid=XXXXX-XXX-XXXXXX" style="color:#1E7EBE;font-weight:bold;">COMMUNITY RULES</a>
          </p>
          <p valign="top" >Please add <strong>%%SENDER%%</strong> to your e-mail address to ensure our e-mails reach your inbox. 
          </p> 
          <p valign="top" >This e-mail was sent from 
           <a href="https://migraine.com/" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Migraine.com</a>, a property of Health Union, LLC, <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;font-weight:bold;">1 International Plaza, Suite 550 Philadelphia, PA 19113</a>. We are sending this e-mail to you on behalf of our sponsor; your e-mail address has not been shared with the sponsor. To unsubscribe, <a href="https://umv5deo8vd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/unsubscribe?info=unsubscribe_hash" style="color:#1E7EBE;font-weight:bold;">click here</a>.</p>
          <p style="padding-top: 10px;" valign="top"><em>&copy;2010-20 Health
           Union. All rights reserved. This information is not     designed to replace a physician's
           independent judgment about the appropriateness or risks of a procedure for a given patient. Always consult your doctor about your medical conditions. 
           <a href="https://migraine.com/" style="text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;color:#1E7EBE">Migraine.com</a> does not provide medical advice, diagnosis or treatment. Use of the site is conditional upon your acceptance of our terms of use.</em>
          </p>
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: can you include the container markup as well?

Comment: Hey zgood, I just updated the code snippet above. Would you be able to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be down to an Outlook quirk which is that it will display images at their true width. 
First off, be really careful with how you declare widths. Using the HTML attribute for width, you should not include the 'px' at the end of the figure. 
When using the CSS property for width, you can then include the 'px' at the end.

```html
<!-- HTML attribute -->
<img src="..." width="227" />

<!-- CSS property -->
<img src="..." style="width:227px;" />
```

Now, back to the issue I found. You've declared the 'd-on-the-go-treatment.png' image with a width of 100%. However, the true width of the image is 642px.
To get around this issue in Outlook, you can change the width declaration to this:

```html
<img src="https://www.migraine.com/weekly/2020-Ubrelvy/d-on-the-go-treatment.png" width="570" style="width:570px; max-width:100%;" alt="A New On-The-Go-Treatment"/>
```

Try that and see how that goes.